# How to write \ symbol in math mode in LaTeX/MathJax?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can we insert the `\` symbol in math mode for LaTeX and MathJax without loading any package that is required to achieve this symbol?

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\$
\end{document}
```

but the program gives errors, also with `${\}$`, `\text{\}` etc. fails. In MathJax I use `$\$` and it produces error.

The context of the problem is I want to represent the (missing) `\` symbol inside a formula (not in SE). The solution is add that symbol, so I want to alert the user "Hey, you forgot to add **`$\$`** in `${1,2,3}$`. It should be `$\{1,2,3\}$`" (of course the site does not have single quotes (`)).

Thanks!!

Comment: Try `\textbackslash` in text mode. But what do you need that symbol for?

Comment: `\backslash` in math mode.

Comment: @siracusa that works in text mode! Good to know. I need it for post an answer regarding how to insert braces in math mode: I wanted to write `\ ` in math mode and not in normal text `:)`.

Comment: “without loading any package” But you are loading `amsmath`!

Comment: @HenriMenke sorry for the confusion. I mean "without loading any package that is needed to achieve the symbol".

Comment: Reading your comment to Henri's answer, I think it would be better to add to your question *why* you want to use a backslash character in math mode. Displaying escaped braces in math mode seems really uncommon to me, so perhaps there is a completely different but better solution to your actual problem (I suspect it has to do with displaying source code)

Comment: @siracusa thank you for your comment. I added something.

Comment: @manooooh The context you added to your question does not really make sense. If you want to represent code, then that is not a formula and you should not need to care about what LaTeX/MathJax do with it. For example, if you write `${1, 2, 3}` in a formula, to the reader it is indistinguishable from the result of `$1, 2, 3$`, so your alert will appear as (except for the font) “Hey you forgot to add \ in 1, 2, 3. It should be {1, 2, 3}” — which is not really useful.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR how would you represent that?

Comment: @manooooh I would use a code block in HTML (or whatever output format you're using): anything except a LaTeX/MathJax formula (because you want to show the literal raw text that is to be input, not the result of treating it as a formula).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR that is a good idea. Unfortunately, I do not program in HTML nor I am the admin of the site, so I think it is quite difficult for me use that language. Also, I do not want to show the formula without formatting.

Comment: @manooooh Well, good luck, let me know how it turns out. I suspect you haven't thought this through, but who knows. (At minimum, I would drop the dollar signs and type just the characters, to avoid them being treated as LaTeX/MathJax.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR thank you `:)`. Of course, without `$$`. P.S. All of the `$$` in the given example is *formatted*.

Comment: Well if you're typing without `$$` then the whole question is meaningless, because then you're *not* trying to write the backslash symbol in math mode. Sigh, we're going in circles; I'll stop.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I want to represent the code, but formatted. It is the same as `\lstinline` command of the `listings` package; represent a piece of code. Of course MathJax does not support that package, so the best idea that came to my mind was formatting the code using `$$`. Sorry for my inaccuracies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably want to use the backslash to exclude elements from a set.  To this end use `\setminus`.  To get the set of all integers without zero, you'd write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{ 0 \}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also works in MathJax.  Live example: http://mathb.in/29559

Comment: I was aware of `\setminus`. As I said in comments, the symbol is for represent the `\ ` required to write braces (here `\{\}`) but I wanted to display it in math mode, so I think the appropiate symbol is `\backslash`.

Comment: @manooooh - You wrote, "I think the appropriate symbol is `\backslash`". That's not quite right, since `\setminus` has math type "mathbin" ("binary operator"), whereas `\backslash` has math type "mathord" ("ordinary"). In order to get the typographically proper amount of spacing around the backslash character, what you would need to write is `\mathbin{\backslash}`.

Answer (score 2):

I often prefer to use `\smallsetminus` because the slash is lower down.

In this link http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html. I have seen that there is a possibility of using it with MathJax.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{R}\smallsetminus\{0\}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\smallsetminus` is a good option, too!

Comment: @manooooh Than you very much and I wish you a prosper a good new year.